# Tkinter disable bind to return key in a Dialog with Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple dialog in my app whose purpose is to allow the user to edit some text properties. The relevant part of the code simplifies to:

```py
from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class PropertiesDialog(Dialog):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Dialog.__init__(self, root)

    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="Description").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.project_description = ScrolledText(master, height=10, width=40)
        self.project_description.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Unfortunately, using the `<Return>` key when typing in the `ScrolledText` field is not interpreted as a line break but as an "OK" by the Dialog, which therefore closes. I thought binding that key to a handler that does nothing would help, but inserting `self.bind("<Return>", self.my_return_handler)` at the beginning of my dialog's `body` method does not intercept anything and inserting it right after `Dialog.__init__(self, root)` raises the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "guitk.py", line 142, in edit_project_properties
    ProjectPropertiesDialog(self.main_window, None)
  File "guitk.py", line 337, in __init__
    self.bind("<Return>", self.return_handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1251, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1206, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!projectpropertiesdialog"
```

How do I fix this? Is there a better suited approach?

Comment: try: widget.bind('<Return>', lambda e: "break") to unbind the default binding on this key.

Comment: you could check Dialog source code and see which widget have binded Return and unbind it. See `import tkinter.simpledialog` `print(tkinter.simpledialog.__file__)`. OR create own Dialog from scratch using `Toplevel()` window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
import tkinter.simpledialog 
print(tkinter.simpledialog.__file__)
```

then you get path to source code and you will see where it binds `<Return>` and then you can remove it.

I copied original `buttonbox()` from source code and commented line which binds `<Return>`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class PropertiesDialog(Dialog):

    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="Description").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.project_description = ScrolledText(master, height=10, width=40)
        self.project_description.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.project_description.focus()

    def buttonbox(self):
        '''add standard button box.

        override if you do not want the standard buttons
        '''

        box = Frame(self)

        w = Button(box, text="OK", width=10, command=self.ok, default=ACTIVE)
        w.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        w = Button(box, text="Cancel", width=10, command=self.cancel)
        w.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        #self.bind("<Return>", self.ok)  # <-- remove it
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.cancel)

        box.pack()

root = Tk()
PropertiesDialog(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** In source code `__init__` you can see it excutes `body` before `buttonbox` so you can't `unbind()` it in `body` because it will bind it after this `unbind()`. You can also see that `__init__` works in different way then normal class - `__init__` waits for closing window - so using it inside `__init__` will be executed after closing Dialog window.

---

**EDIT:** Info for other users - as Anthony Labarre mentioned in comment it is simpler method

```
def buttonbox(self):
    super().buttonbox()
    self.unbind("<Return>")
    #self.bind("<Control-Return>", self.ok)  # bind other combination to OK
```

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class PropertiesDialog(Dialog):

    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="Description").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.project_description = ScrolledText(master, height=10, width=40)
        self.project_description.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.project_description.focus()

    def buttonbox(self):
        super().buttonbox()
        self.unbind("<Return>")
        #self.bind("<Control-Return>", self.ok)  # bind other combination to OK

root = Tk()
PropertiesDialog(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly assumed everything was set up in `__init__`. Thanks, this works exactly as intended.

Comment: I ended up rewriting `buttonbox` as `Dialog.buttonbox(self); self.unbind("<Return>")`. Same effect, cleaner to me.

Comment: you are right. It is much simpler. I add it to answer - it can be useful for other users.